# How could I go about proving that $\dim U = \dim V + \dim V^{\bot}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How could I go about proving that $$\dim \ U = \dim \ V + \dim \ V^{\bot}$$

Where $U$ is a finite dim vector space.
If I know that $V$ is a subspace of $U$, and let $V^{\bot}$ be the set of all vectors $s \in U$ and that the inner product $\langle v,s \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Can I use the fact $U = V \oplus V^{\bot}$?

Comment: Do you mean $U=V\oplus V^\perp$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form; dimension formulae.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583100/non-degenerate-symmetric-bilinear-form-dimension-formulae)

Comment: The fact that $U = V \oplus V^{\bot}$ implies the dimension formula, but that means it is unlikely that you could prove it more easily than proving the dimension formula. So you should ask yourself: if you are unsure about the dimensions, how do you know that the sum is direct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you can prove that $U = V \oplus V^⊥$ then the dimension result follows almost straight away. Recall that $\dim (U+V)+ \dim(U\cap V) = \dim(U) + \dim (V)$ and the definition of direct sum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use $U = V \oplus V^\perp$.  Show that if you have a basis for $A$ and a basis for $B$ then together they give a basis for $A \oplus B$.  This gives $\dim A \oplus B = \dim A + \dim B$.